# Makefile with if statement error

Tags: scripts, makefile

Attempting to create a `makefile` with a `run` rule which has an if in it.

When I run the command `make run` it returns this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
```

The name of the file is `Makefile`. What can I do? (I created this `Makefile` with Vim editor and the format of Vim is already set to unix).

This is a part of the code:

```bsh
#!bin/bash

#other rules 

run:

    if ls exec &>/dev/null
    then
            gcc -o exec file1.o file2.o
            ./exec
    else
           ./exec
    fi
```

Comment: `if ls exec &>/dev/null`  is not valid bash. https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html and you can drop the `else` No need for 2x `./exec`

Comment: but how do i check if the exec file exists if ls exec &>/dev/null is not a valid bash?

Comment: Look at the link on how if's are formatted: you lack at least the [ and ] and a ; If this is bash that is :)

Comment: ok, so i changed if to this : if [ ls exec &>dev/null ]; then   and still got another error : /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected

Comment: I got what you wanted and updated the answer. So you want to compile if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statement should look this way if you want to check existence of `exec`.

```
if [ ! -f exec ]; then
    gcc -o exec file1.o file2.o
fi

./exec
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixing shell code into a Makefile in that way almost certainly won't work the way you expect (if it works at all).

In particular, each shell command line will be executed in its own subshell - using `/bin/sh` by default - hence why you are see errors like

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
```

from `/bin/sh` in spite of the `#!/bin/bash` shebang (which `make` will see as a pure comment).

Since the whole purpose of `make` is to test for the presence and modification status of prerequisites, you can define a `run` target that conditionally builds its executable prerequisite if it is absent or out of date as follows:

```
executable: file1.o file2.o
        gcc -o executable file1.o file2.o

run: executable
        ./executable
```

**Note: I named the executable program `executable` since the name `exec` conflicts with the name of a shell builtin.**

or, more idiomatically, using `make`'s [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for targets and prerequisites:

```
CC      := gcc
OBJS    := file1.o file2.o

executable: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^

run: executable
        ./$<
```

Testing with `make -n`:

```
$ touch file1.c file2.c

$ make -n run
gcc    -c -o file1.o file1.c
gcc    -c -o file2.o file2.c
gcc -o executable file1.o file2.o
./executable
```